# how to delete the last created file and rename the other files in sequence in c programming

Tags: c, linux

there are certain files in a directory
ex:  log.0
log.1
log.2
log.3
log.4
I want to delete the last created file and rename the other files in sequence.
here log.0 is the last created file. I want to delete this and rename the other files with the sequence 0,1,2,3..

The code I used is as follows

```
    char buffer[30];
    char  cmd[30];
    FILE *fpipe;
    char newLogFileName[30];
    char oldLogFileName[30];
    int fcount = 0;
    int max_files = 5;
    int ret;

    sprintf(cmd, "ls -rt | head -n 1");
    if (0 == (fpipe = (FILE*)popen(commandBuff, "r")))
           {
             printf("popen failed %s\n", strerror(errno) );
            }
     ret = fscanf(fpipe, "%s", buffer);
     pclose(fpipe);
    
     sprintf(cmd , "rm %s", buffer);
     ret = system(cmd);
    
     for ( fcount = max_files - 1; fcount >= 0; --fcount)
     {
         snprintf(oldLogFileName, sizeof(oldLogFileName),
                         "log.%d",  fcount );
                snprintf(newLogFileName, sizeof(newLogFileName),
                         "log.%d", fcount - 1);
                rename(oldLogFileName, newLogFileName);
     }
```

couldn't get the result. please suggest any changes that I have to do to solve it

Comment: `sprintf(cmd , "rm %s", buffer);` => `remove(buffer)`. Also never parse the output of `ls`

Comment: after removing log.0 which one of log.4 or log.1 would be the new log.0?

Comment: log.4 will be the new log

Comment: I would use [`opendir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) to get a list of the filenames in the directory, rather than `popen` and `ls`.

Comment: Not trying to make your job more complicated, but just a comment: If the program(s) that are *creating* `log.0`, `log.1`, etc. are running at the same time, you'll have to worry about the possibility that they'll interfere with your program, and perhaps devise a scheme (some kind of locking mechanism?) to guard against that.

Comment: This is a great learning exercise as a C program, but if you just want to get your log files renamed in a hurry, it would probably be quicker and easier to do this as a shell script.

Comment: you can't use logrotate ?

Comment: You have `fpipe = (FILE*)popen(...`.  You should *not* need that `(FILE *)` cast.  If you put it there to silence a warning, the warning indicates a more serious problem which you need to fix.  Do you have the line `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your source file?  If not, you need it, and it ought to make that warning go away, and you should be able to get rid of the cast.

Comment: To clarify: what do _you_ mean by "last created"? Do you mean oldest (i.e. lowest `st_mtime`)? Or, do you mean "the last file that was created" (i.e. highest `st_mtime`)? Also, if you're creating the files in sequence (oldest to newest) and appending the sequence number to the end of the file, you may _not_ need to `stat` the file. Just `unlink` the log.0 file and rename all the other log.* files accordingly. Or, is the situation more complex: the mtimes of the files do _not_ correspond with the file extension (e.g. log.0 created on Tuesday but log.1 created on Monday)?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one of several possible approaches:

1. Use [scandir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) (or [glob()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)) to get the current log file names.  Sort them into the proper order (either as a scandir() filter, or using [qsort()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)). Rename each file in the array to the previous file name (no need to delete anything, because renaming over an existing file replaces the existing file atomically). Write the new file using the last file name in the array.

   This has the downside that there must be at least two log files already.  Also, if the user deletes say file 'log.2', then no new 'log.2' will be created, only the existing 'log.0', 'log.1', 'log.3', and 'log.4' rotated.
2. Use [scandir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) (or [glob()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)) to get the current log file names.  Sort them into the proper order (either as a scandir() filter, or using [qsort()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)).  Starting with the *second* log file name in the array, rename it to 'log.0', the third to 'log.1', and so on, incrementing the number by one for each log file name. This "compacts" the log file list, removing any "holes" in the numbering.  The new log file will have the next incremented number.

   You can also set a maximum number of log files kept, by checking if the count (of log file names in the array) has reached maximum yet.  If not, rename the *first* log file name in the array to 'log.0', and so on, keeping all the existing log files (but removing any "holes" in the numbering).  The new log file will still have the next incremented number.
3. Use [scandir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) with a filter that always returns zero (so scandir() will return no files), but only updates the minimum and maximum log file numbers (as global variables).  This gives you the log file number range, so you can use a simple loop to rename each log file (that exists) to the previous number.

   If the user deletes one or more of the log files, those rename() operations will fail with `errno == ENOENT`; this is simply ignored.  This way, those "holes" will percolate through the log file list as usual, and no compaction will occur.
4. Use a loop over [stat()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to find the initial consecutive range of log files.  If 'log.0' does not exist, you save the new log file to 'log.0'.  If you wish to keep up to fifteen log files, if any of 'log.1' to 'log.13' does not exist, you save the new log file there.  If all fifteen log files, 'log.0' to 'log.14', exist, you rename 'log.1' to 'log.0', 'log.2' to 'log.1', and so on through to 'log.13' to 'log.12', and 'log.14' to 'log.13', and save the new log file to 'log.14'.

   When the number of log files to be kept is reasonably small (say, less than a hundred), this is very efficient.  The only downside is that if the user deletes a log file by hand, the next new log file will be saved in that "hole", thus possibly mangling the order.

---

In all cases I recommend using a simple dynamically allocated memory pattern to construct the file names using [snprintf()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) safely.  You start by allocating a small initial buffer, say 128 bytes:

```c
    char   *name;
    size_t  size = 128;

    name = malloc(size);
    if (!name) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Then, when you wish to generate the path based on `LOG_NAME_PATTERN` (say, `"log.%d"`, or `"/var/log/myapp/log.%d"`) and `int count`, you do

```c
    while (1) {
        int  len = snprintf(name, size, LOG_NAME_PATTERN, count);
        if (len < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid LOG_NAME_PATTERN (%s).\n", LOG_NAME_PATTERN);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else
        if ((size_t)len >= size) {
            /* Resize buffer to anything larger than len */
            const size_t  new_size = ((size_t)len | 15) + 17;
            char         *new_name;
            if (new_size <= (size_t)len) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Path pattern is too long.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            new_name = realloc(name, new_size);
            if (!new_name) {
                /* Note: name is still valid! */
                fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            name = new_name;
            size = new_size;
            continue;
        }

        /* Have correct path in name. */
        break;
    }
```

The above loop resizes (reallocates) the buffer when necessary.

Also note that if the above has succeeded for some nonnegative `count`, then you can safely allocate another buffer using

```c
    char *newname = malloc(size);
    if (!newname) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

and then you can safely use `(void)snprintf(name, size, LOG_NAME_PATTERN, count)` or `(void)snprintf(name, size, LOG_NAME_PATTERN, i)` for any `int i` where `i` is nonnegative and not greater than `count` –– as you need for the rename() operations.

I prefer to use a preprocessor macro for the log file name pattern. For example,

```c
#ifndef  LOG_NAME_PATTERN
#define  LOG_NAME_PATTERN  "log.%d"
#endif
```

Then, at compile time, one can use `-DLOG_NAME_PATTERN="/var/log/myapp.%d"` (in say `CFLAGS` in the Makefile, or directly as a parameter to GCC or Clang or whatever C compiler you use) to override the above default.  (The quotes are necessary; but they can also be added using a couple of helper preprocessor macros.)

---

In general, applications should probably use the system logging facilities: [openlog("myapplication", LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID, LOG_USER)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openlog.3.html) at the beginning of the process, then [syslog(LOG_ERR, "format", ...)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) to log the errors.

Let's assume there is some reason why that is not a reasonable approach, and explore the other options.

Typically, application log file is `/var/log/application.log` or `/var/log/application/name.log` (with different `name` parts).  The application always uses append mode (via `O_APPEND` or `"a"`).

Older log files are in `/var/log/application.log.#` or `/var/log/application/name.log.#` with `#` being a decimal number starting with 1; or in compressed when rotated, in `/var/log/application.log.#.EXT` or `/var/log/application.log.#.EXT` where `EXT` is `gz`, `bz2`, or `xz`.  These older log files are considered *archived*: read-only, not to be modified/appended to.

In these cases, only the current log file (`/var/log/application.log` or `/var/log/application/name.log`) is being appended to.  The log file rotator renames this log file temporarily, then usually sends a signal (typically HUP) to the service process so it knows to re-open the log file.  It then waits until the service process no longer has the temporarily renamed log file open, before compressing the log file, and then does the log rotation.  (Privileged processes and processes running as the same user as the target file can take an [exclusive file lease](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) to verify no other process has the file open.  If the first archived log file (.log.1) is not compressed, the log rotator does not need to check if it is still open.)

Typically, a sane service or application uses logrotate to rotate its logs, by dropping a logrotate configuration snippet as /etc/logrotate.d/application.  The `postrotate` .. `endscript` part is a command that tells the application, if it is currently running, to close its current log file, and reopen it.  It is usually a command that connects to the application; sending SIGHUP for this is particularly common.

Here is a trivial example program you can treat as such a service:

```c
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <signal.h>
// MT: #include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  LOG_TIME
#define  LOG_TIME  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.^^^ %Z: "
#endif

#ifndef  LOG_FILE
#define  LOG_FILE  "myapp.log"
#endif

#ifndef  PID_FILE
#define  PID_FILE  "myapp.pid"
#endif

// MT: static pthread_mutex_t log_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static volatile sig_atomic_t  log_reopen = 0;
static int                    log_fd = -1;

int  log_print(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list  args;
    int      fd, len, tlen;

    /* Don't bother if no format. */
    if (!format || !*format)
        return 0;

    // MT: pthread_mutex_lock(&log_lock);

    fd = log_fd;

    if (log_reopen) {
        log_reopen = 0;
        if (fd != -1) {
            close(fd);
            fd = -1;
        }
    }

    if (fd == -1) {
        do {
            fd = open(LOG_FILE, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0666);
        } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (fd == -1) {
            // MT: pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_lock);
            return -1;
        }
        log_fd = fd;
    }

    tlen = 0;

#ifdef  LOG_TIME
    const char  *timefmt = LOG_TIME;
    do {
        if (!timefmt || !*timefmt)
            break;

        struct timespec  now_ts;
        struct tm        now;

        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now_ts) == -1) {
            now_ts.tv_sec = time(NULL);
            now_ts.tv_nsec = 0L;
        }
        if (localtime_r(&now_ts.tv_sec, &now) != &now)
            break;


        char    stamp[128];
        size_t  stamplen = strftime(stamp, sizeof stamp, LOG_TIME, &now);
        if (!stamplen)
            break;

        char *dst = strchr(stamp, '^');
        if (dst) {
            unsigned long  value = now_ts.tv_nsec;
            int            digits = 1;

            while (dst[digits] == '^')
                digits++;

            while (digits > 9)
                dst[--digits] = '0';

            switch (digits) {
            case 9: dst[8] = '0' + ( value                % 10uL);
            case 8: dst[7] = '0' + ((value /        10uL) % 10uL);
            case 7: dst[6] = '0' + ((value /       100uL) % 10uL);
            case 6: dst[5] = '0' + ((value /      1000uL) % 10uL);
            case 5: dst[4] = '0' + ((value /     10000uL) % 10uL);
            case 4: dst[3] = '0' + ((value /    100000uL) % 10uL);
            case 3: dst[2] = '0' + ((value /   1000000uL) % 10uL);
            case 2: dst[1] = '0' + ((value /  10000000uL) % 10uL);
            case 1: dst[0] = '0' + ((value / 100000000uL) % 10uL);
            }
        }

        const char *const end = stamp + stamplen;
        const char       *src = stamp;
        while (src  < end) {
            ssize_t  n = write(fd, src, (size_t)(end - src));
            if (n > 0) {
                src += n;
            } else
            if (n != -1 || errno != EINTR) {
                close(fd);
                log_fd = -1;
                // MT: pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_lock);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        tlen = (int)stamplen;
    } while (0);
#endif

    va_start(args, format);
    len = vdprintf(fd, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    // MT: pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_lock);

    if (len < 0) {
        return len;
    } else {
        return len + tlen;
    }
}

static void log_rotate(int signum)
{
    log_reopen = 1;

    /* Silence warning about unused parameter; generates no code. */
    (void)signum;
}

int install_log_rotate_signal(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = log_rotate;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    return sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);
}


/*
 * The following is only for testing this as a program;
 * CTRL-C, SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTERM will terminate it cleanly.
*/

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    done = 1;
    (void)signum;
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    return sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);
}

static int  create_pidfile(void)
{
    const char *path = PID_FILE;
    int         fd, len;

    do {
        fd = open(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    len = dprintf(fd, "%ld\n", (long)getpid());
    if (len < 1) {
        unlink(path);
        close(fd);
        return errno = EIO;
    }

    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        unlink(path);
        return errno = EIO;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void  remove_pidfile(void)
{
    unlink(PID_FILE);
}

static double  dsleep(const double seconds)
{
    struct timespec  req, rem;

    if (seconds > 0.0) {
        req.tv_sec  = (long)seconds;
        req.tv_nsec = (seconds - (double)req.tv_sec) * 1000000000L;
        /* Check for rounding error */
        if (req.tv_nsec < 0L)
            req.tv_nsec = 0L;
        else
        if (req.tv_nsec > 999999999L)
            req.tv_nsec = 999999999L;
    } else {
        req.tv_sec  = 0;
        req.tv_nsec = 0L;
    }

    if (nanosleep(&req, &rem) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            return seconds - (double)rem.tv_sec - (double)rem.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
        else
            return -1.0;
    }

    return seconds;
}


int main(void)
{
    if (install_log_rotate_signal(SIGHUP) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGINT) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGQUIT) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGTERM) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (create_pidfile()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create PID file '%s': %s.\n", PID_FILE, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (!done) {
        double  s = dsleep(5.0);
        log_print("Slept %.3f seconds.\n", s);
    }

    remove_pidfile();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Above, `LOG_FILE` is the path to the log file (usually `/var/log/myapplication.log` or `/var/log/myapplication/name.log`), `PID_FILE` is the path to the PID file (usually `/var/run/myapplication.pid`), and `LOG_TIME` is the timestamp prepended to each log event in [strftime()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) format in local time, except with consecutive `^` characters are replaced with the fractional seconds.  (So, `"%S.^^^"` yields seconds using three decimals, and `"%s.^^^^^^^^^" yields the Unix epoch time at nanosecond precision.)

The `// MT:` lines are needed if the application is multithreaded.

If you change `PID_FILE` to `/var/run/myapp.pid` and `LOG_FILE` to `/var/log/myapp/myapp.log`, and make `/var/log/myapp/` writable to the user running the above program, you can use `logrotate` with the following snippet (`/etc/logrotate.d/myapp`) to rotate its log files daily, keeping up to 15 files, compressing archived log files:

```logrotate
/var/log/myapp/myapp.log {
    rotate 15
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        kill -HUP `cat /var/run/myapp.pid` >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```